# How do can I update a Form using shell/bash script on Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, script, shell-script, cron

I am wondering is it possible to echo values like below described? The situation is - there are too many "doc" files named like "PLCI507_01234567.doc", and there is a Form in a text file named "form.txt" looks like below;

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Date: 
Count :
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ID   | Host    | md5sum               | Created   | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
       |         |                    |           |
     |         |                      |           | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I am already able to create files in the same format for each documents but now I want all the information in a single form and the form should be updated with file informations ie. file name, created date, md5sum etc.

md5sum = `md5sum PLCI507_01234567.doc | awk '{ print $1 }' #sum of each file`

Created = `date +"%d/%m/%Y" #date of form update`

The updated form.txt should be like below.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Date: 4/14/2011 
Count : 4 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ID     | Host    | md5sum                           | Created    | 
--------------------------------------------------------------------
01234567 | PLCI507 | 2b3dbf39a65eb140a163401001e32fb2 | 14/03/2011 | 
01234560 | PLCI512 | 7aa31c83cc1b78fa9ae60460e1eb4731 | 22/04/2011 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please some body help me with this. I am hoping that there must be some way to do it.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a script that will generate this file, and print it nicely with printf.

Just call it like: `./script_name.sh /path/to/docfiles/`

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

docFiles=$(find "$1" -iname '*.doc')
numFiles=$(echo -e "$docFiles" | wc -l)

sep="--------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
Date="Date: $(date +'%d/%m/%Y')"
Count="Count : $numFiles"

# Start printing file
echo $sep
echo $Date
echo $Count
echo $sep
printf ' %-10s | %-10s | %-33s | %-15s |\n' "ID" "Host" "md5sum" "Created"
echo $sep


for file in $docFiles
do
    docMD5=$(md5sum "$file" | awk '{ print $1 }')
    # This was a bit unclear in the question...
    # if you want file mtime instead... use something like:
    #docDate=$(stat -c %d/%m/%Y "$file")
    #docDate=${docDate%% *}

    docID=$(basename "$file" | sed -e 's/^\(.*\)_.*/\1/')
    docHost=$(basename "$file" | sed -e 's/^.*_\(.*\)\.doc$/\1/')

    # Use today's date
    docDate=$(date +"%d/%m/%Y")
    printf ' %-10s | %-10s | %-33s | %-15s |\n' "$docID" "$docHost" "$docMD5" "$docDate"
done

echo $sep
```

- Copy/paste with your favorite editor whatever filename you want to call it.
- `chmod +x script_name.sh`
- `./script_name.sh /path/to/docfiles/`

Comment: works fine, but if I run this script in the same directory next time it generates results for old one too.. :( and if if i push the result to a text tile, next time it creates new file but with old informations too... any solution for avoiding old file and update only single file?

Comment: How exactly should it work?  If you run it on all the files in the directory a second time... should it only look for new files?  What about changed files?
Also, is the "Created" field supposed to be mtime, ctime, or just `date +"%d/%m/%Y"`?   
  
It sounds like you want it to update a single file... what is the expected behavior?

Comment: the directory has lots of files uploaded every minute and yes it should only look for new files then update the record a file. I think it's better to check with Created mtime or md5sum ??

Answer (score 1):

it seems you need a loop to access each .doc file

```
i=0
for f in *.doc
do
    ((i++))
    f=$(basename "$f")

    # process each file
    # ...

    form_content="${form_content}$f_id | $f_host | $md5sum | $Created |\n"
done
```

if .doc files have fixed length name, you can strip host/id via [`Parameter Expansion`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).

```
f_host="${f:0:7}"
f_id="${f:8:8}"
```

finally, output the result like:

```
echo "--------------------"
echo "Date: `date +%d/%m/%Y`"
echo "Count: $i"
echo "--------------------"
echo "ID | Host | md5sum | Created |"
echo "--------------------"
echo -e "$form_content"
echo "--------------------"
```